# Ignoring part of a tuple returned in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

With the following code, is there any way to specify that I don't care about the 'address' part of the tuple returned?

```
(data, address) = socket.recvfrom(512)
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
data = socket.recvfrom(512)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
data = socket.recvfrom(512)[0]
```

Comment: `_` is special in the interpreter, so many folks *don't* use it, since pasting it will be annoying.  names with leading underscores, though, `_dontcare` or `_ignored` are fine, though.

Answer (score 3):

option one, just grab the elements you are intereseted in:

```
data = socket.recvfrom(512)[0]
```

option two, use a word that tells the reader you don't care:

```
data, dummy = socket.recvfrom(512)
```

Comment: One option for the "don't care" name is bare `_`, which serves that function in some other languages anyway.